# Manipulate: Show result in Engineering/Scientific Form

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

I have a simple definition as follows and the result expected is in either `EngineeringForm` or `ScientificForm`

```
DurationOfAcquistion[RatePerSec_, RecordLength_] := 
  EngineeringForm[RecordLength/RatePerSec];

DurationOfAcquistion[20.*10^6, 1000] (* results in 50.x10^-6 *)
Manipulate[
 DurationOfAcquistion[r, rl], {r, 20*10^6, 1.25*10^9}, {rl, 1000, 
  125*10^6}]
```

[image: 1]

When I deploy the same function definition using `Manipulate`, I can't seem to get it in either Engineering/Scientific form. I am currently using MMA 11.3 release. Can someone please confirm if this is how it's supposed to be or is there an alternative way?

---

***EDIT***

**I really have to apologize, this may be like a bug in output format display, but not a serious one. I was able to see the output in `EngineeringForm` once I started manipulating the sliders >>> Please watch the GIF [here](https://i.imgur.com/BzNjIj9.gifv).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the initial value of `r` or `rl` a real, instead of an integer (otherwise the initial value of `rl / r` will be a rational).  For example:

```
Manipulate[EngineeringForm[rl / r],
  {r, 20.0*10^6, 1.25*10^9},{rl, 1000.0, 125*10^6}]
```

In this case the initial values of both `r` and `rl` are reals, but you only need to make one of them real.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[N @ DurationOfAcquistion[r, rl], {r, 20*10^6, 1.25*10^9}, {rl, 1000, 125*10^6}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, change the right-hand-side to

```
EngineeringForm[1. RecordLength/RatePerSec]
```

when you define `DurationOfAcquistion`.